# SVG print issue in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

When I draw SVG stripes with a pattern  and print it in Google Chrome, some lines become ugly like this.

[image]

This does not happen in other browsers. For example, in Microsoft Edge, like this.
[image]

How can I print this properly in Google Chrome? Or is there anything wrong in this code?

Here is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
 <defs>
  <pattern id="pattern_qET8y" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
   <line x1="0" y="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#24194D" stroke-width="1" />
  </pattern>
 </defs>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%"  fill="url(#pattern_qET8y)"/>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alternatively I could print it properly by converting SVG to img using canvas

Comment: This might be a bug in Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=967418